# React Native - No connection to Smartphone using Expo

Tags: ubuntu, expo, python-re, wsl-2

I'm making a new project with React Native, and I'm using Ubuntu on WSL on Windows 10.  I'm also using Expo on my smartphone in the same network with `expo start --tunnel`.   But after some period of time, I get the error:

```
Cannot connect to Metro.

Try the following to fix the issue:

Ensure that Metro is running and available on the same network

Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices

If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device

If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server - e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081
URL: q3-fmi.anonymous.sistema-mobile-fluxo.exp.direct:80

Error: null at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/vendor/eventemitter3.js:195:15 in emit at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js:50:6 in _ws.onerror at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js:271:8 in _eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1 at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:150:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

Answer (score 0):

> on my smartphone in the same network

That's almost certainly the core issue.  WSL2 isn't on the "same network" as your smart phone (or any other device).  It's on a *separate*, virtual network that is NAT'd behind a virtual switch on the Windows host.  Other devices on the network cannot directly connect to WSL2 without additional port forwarding.

You have at least four options, which I document fully in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986).  I've also documented options in other Stack Overflow questions here, but the Ask Ubuntu is currently has the latest, including my personal preference of using `ssh` to port forward.

In almost every case where I've answered this, the accepted solution was to convert to WSL1 using `wsl --set-version <distro> 1`.  I also cover how to make a backup of your instance before converting in that linked answer.